# ETH 2.0 but I have yet to claim my ETH from presale

Tags: presale, eth-2.0

Had to deal with life and lost track of ETH after the crash. I have yet to claim my ETH presale and wanted to know with all the forks and now ETH 2.0, can someone go over the best way to claim my ETH but also receive any fork coins? Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: See if this help https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5w6719/help_how_to_import_a_presale_wallet_without/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll contact MEW to verify I can still claim an ETH presale without any issues. If anyone has any additional information about claiming fork coins. I would be grateful!

Comment: It is likely there will be another fork in the second semester, but it will not be controversial so everybody will follow it. Eth 2.0 is still in the research/early implementation so there are not plans for the transition yet.